# Word 'mortal' in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

I read a story about the legend of Ethiopia. I found a confusing part at the end of the story. The sentence is below.

> Perseus immediately fell in love with Andromeda, and carried her off to be his bride. Needless to say, the joy and celebration in the kingdom of Ethiopia knew no bounds, and the figures of the Andromeda story were placed in the sky as an eternal reminder of the dangers of *mortal* arrogance.

In the sentence, does the highlighted word "mortal" mean 'human' or 'serious'?

If it means human , is it the case that noun modifies noun?

Answer (score 1):

In Greek mythology, "mortal" usually refers to attributes associated with humans as opposed to gods. The former have a short life and have very little power. The latter live long, if not forever, and have jurisdictional powers. Mythology often "exposes" the many cons, and sometimes the pros, of both mortality and immortality. Mortal arrogance may mean, "the arrogance of humans" or perhaps, though much less likely, "the arrogance which makes one mortal." Please be aware that I am not familiar with this story.

[Mortal](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/mortal) can be an adjective or a noun.

Comment: Your detailed explanation help me understand things cleraly. I totally agree with your opinion. Thank you.

Comment: @tammy I'm very glad to hear that; you're very welcome!